# How to connect to windows postgres Database from WSL

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Postgres 11 service on my Windows computer.
How can I connect to this database from WSL?

When I try `su - postgres`:

```
postgres@LAPTOP-NQ52TKOG:~$ psql 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

It's trying to connect to a Postgres in WSL. I don't want to run Ubuntu Postgres using:
`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start`

Comment: Is Postgres running on Windows inside WSL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specify your host, port, and username explicitly
For example:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Comment: I'm getting `psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` The same command works fine in Windows console though...

Answer (score 106):

WSL2 assigns IP address to the Windows host dynamically and the IP addresses can change without even rebooting Windows (see Notes below). So to reliably connect we'll need to:

1. Allow Windows and Postgres to accept connections from the WSL2 IP address range (not allowed by default)
2. From WSL2, determine the Windows/Postgresql host's IP address (which is dynamic) when connecting via `psql`. We'll make this convenient via `.bashrc` and `alias`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the exact specification for the WSL2 IP address range. From several tests/reboots it appears that WSL2 is assigning IP addresses primarily in range of `172.*.*.*` but I have occasionally been assigned `192.*.*.*` so we'll use these when configuring the firewall and Postgres.

**Add Windows Firewall Inbound Port Rule for WSL2 IP Addresses:**

1. Open `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security`
2. Click `New Rule...`
3. Select `Port` for rule type
4. Select `TCP` and for `Specific local ports` enter `5432`
5. Select `Allow the connection`. Connecting from WSL2 won't be secure so don't select the secure option
6. Select at least `Public`. Can select `Domain` and `Private` as well. I could only connect if `Public` was selected
7. Name the rule e.g. `Postgres - connect from WSL2` and create it
8. Right click newly created rule and select `Properties` then click on the `Scope` tab
9. Under `Remote IP address`, select `These IP addresses` then click `Add...` and enter range `172.0.0.1` to `172.254.254.254`
10. Repeat step 9 for IP address range `192.0.0.1` to `192.254.254.254`
11. Click `Apply` then `OK`
12. Make sure rule is enabled

**Configure Postgres to Accept Connections from WSL2 IP Addresses**

Assuming a default install/setup of Postgresql for Windows the following files are located under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\$VERSION\data`

Verify that `postgresql.conf` has following set:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

This should already be set to `'*'` so nothing do here.

Update `pg_hba.conf` to allow connections from WSL2 range e.g. for Postgresl 12:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             172.0.0.0/8             md5
host    all             all             192.0.0.0/8             md5
```

For Postgresql 13+ you should use `scram-sha-256` as the method.

Restart Postgres for changes to take effect. This can be done either from the Windows `Services` app or from `cmd` with Administrator privileges e.g. for Postgresql 12:

```
net stop postgresql-x64-12
net start postgresql-x64-12
```

**WSL Shell Conveniences**

In WSL, add following to your `~/.bashrc` or similar:

```bash
# Add DNS entry for Windows host
if ! $(cat /etc/hosts | grep -q 'winhost'); then
  echo 'Adding DNS entry for Windows host in /etc/hosts'
  echo '\n# Windows host - added via ~/.bashhrc' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
  echo -e "$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2, "   winhost"}')" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
fi
```

Then reload your `.bashrc` changes: `source ~/.bashrc`

**Usage**

```bash
psql -h winhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

**Notes:**

- The IP address assigned to the Windows host by WSL2 is not the same as the IP address assigned to your physical Windows machine on your network. WSL2 uses `vEthernet` connections.
- You can inspect the `vEthernet` connections via `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`
- Note that when looking at the IPv4 properties that the IP addresses will appear as if they are statically set but they aren't! Try rebooting and inspecting IPv4 properties again
- If one day you're unable to connect to Postgres, check that `winhost` is in the IP address range per firewall rules. Could be WSL has assigned an IP address that we weren't expecting!

Comment: To get this working on PosgreSQL v13 the following changes are necessary:

1. Remove `listen_addresses = '*'`  since this will prevent postgresql from starting up.

2. In `pg_hba.conf`, i set the `METHOD` to `scram-sha-256`.

Also note that by default PosgreSQL 13 listens on port `5433`.

Comment: As of October 2021, this is probably the only solution that works. Just using `nameserver ` for the hostname doesn't connect to Postgres in Windows from wsl2

Comment: Excellent answer. In my case, since my machine has Windows 11 home, I had to enable hypervisor, via the method suggested, here: https://beebom.com/how-enable-hyper-v-windows-11-home/. It appears not to be enabled and available, by default, with Windows 11 home.

Comment: Your IP ranges are too large and includes public addresses. The possible private network blocks are `172.16.0.0/12`,  `192.168.0.0/16` and `10.0.0.0/8`. However, your LAN or domain network is probably using one of them.

Comment: To get the IP(s) of your Windows machine inside WSL, do `dig +short ${HOSTNAME}.local`.

Comment: To get the IP(s) of your WSL environment, do `ip address show eth0`

Answer (score 23):

In WSL2 you need to use host IP to connect

to get host IP

`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'`

then you need to allow TCP 5432 inbound Rules in 'Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security'

---

I made my self PS.you still need to allow TCP 5432 in Firewall

put this in ~/.bashrc

`cat /etc/hosts | grep 172.; test $? -eq 0 && $1 || echo -e "$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2, " host"}')\n$(cat /etc/hosts)" | sudo tee /etc/hosts`

its append host IP to /etc/hosts if not exist before(usually happened when restart wsl or computer)

then

```
psql -h host -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

For me what worked was to follow these steps:

- Change pg_hba.conf to listen on all interfaces: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust`
- Open firewall for postgresql
- Use one of the hostnames in `/etc/hosts` that pointed to the ip of my host. This hostname for me was: `host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed in two possible ways

Specify the host and user name explicitly

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Or

Navigate to the runpsql.sh file and run the query

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/14/scripts/runpsql.sh
```

Now run the psql query by entering password (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I found that WSL 2 does give this error:

psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

But WSL 1 does not.

I had two different WSL distros running of Ubuntu one on WSL 1 and one on WSL 2 and tested connectivity in WSL 1 and my connection there was successful.

I downgraded the other one and re-tested and it worked as well.  I re-upgraded and I got the error.

WSL 2 is a more complete (see here...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) and is a full Linux Kernel and Managed VM whereas WSL 1 is not.

If you are like me, and your requirements are not as stringent for testing (and switching to the admin user to take care of the firewall and postgres settings on your work laptop is a laborious process as it is for me) and you just need to test from Linux as I did, you can install another WSL and leave it at 1 or even downgrade.  Of note though this then will not support Rancher Desktop as it needs WSL 2.  Docker Desktop installs WSL 2 so that should not be a consideration.

More info here to see your WSL versions etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect to my postgres-db on windows from my WSL2 after having the same problem..
Some of my steps might be redundant, but hopefully it leads the discussion towards greater insights. Here are my steps:

1. Make sure postgresql.conf had `listen_addresses = '*'`
2. Open firewall inbound rule to allow any ips for port 5432
3. Add host to pg_hba.conf by adding the following line: 
   `host    all             all             172.xx.xx.0/20          scram-sha-256`

The ip-address "172.xx.xx.x" was attained through running ipconfig and taking the IPv4 Address under the Ethernet Adapter WSL section.

Now after all this, I am pretty sure it still wasn't working for me. However, I found an additional way of allowing inbound traffic from the WSL network..
Run the following in an elevated powershell (you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585)):

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))" -Action Allow
```

You might have to change interface alias to whatever you see at "Ethernet Adapter" when running ipconfig in windows cmd. These last two steps were most likely what did it for me. Hope this helps!