# Error connection to server at "localhost", port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build API(with FastAPI) using python. I have installed python on windows WSL(ubuntu)
and I have postgress on Windows. Now I'm trying to connect to Postgresssql via python code like below. but the connection is failing with **Connection refused** error

**code:**

```
try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',database='fastapi',password='xxxx',cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("Database connection was successfull")
    except Exception as error:
        print("Connetion to database has failed")
        print("Error", error)
```

**Error**

```
Connetion to database has failed
Error connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have gone through below link from from Stackoverflow but luck, can you please advice what could be the issue.

[How to connect to windows postgres Database from WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824788/how-to-connect-to-windows-postgres-database-from-wsl)

**Steps followed from the above link**

**Add Windows Firewall Inbound Port Rule for WSL2 IP Addresses:**

1. Open Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
2. Click New Rule...
3. Select Port for rule type
4. Select TCP and for Specific local ports enter 5432
5. Select Allow the connection. Connecting from WSL2 won't be secure so don't select the secure option
6. Select at least Public. Can select Domain and Private as well. I could only connect if Public was selected
7. Name the rule e.g. Postgres - connect from WSL2 and create it
8. Right click newly created rule and select Properties then click on the Scope tab
9. Under Remote IP address, select These IP addresses then click Add... and enter range 172.0.0.1 to 172.254.254.254
   10.Repeat step 9 for IP address range 192.0.0.1 to 192.254.254.254
   11.Click Apply then OK
   12.Make sure rule is enabled

**Configure Postgres to Accept Connections from WSL2 IP Addresses**

Assuming a default install/setup of Postgresql for Windows the following files are located under

```
C:\Program Files\PostgresSQL\$VERSION\data
```

Verify that postgresql.conf has following set:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

This should already be set to '*' so nothing do here.

Update pg_hba.conf to allow connections from WSL2 range e.g. for Postgresl 15:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32       scram-sha-256
host    all             all             172.0.0.0/8        scram-sha-256
host    all             all             192.0.0.0/8        scram-sha-256
```

For **Postgresql 13+** you should use **scram-sha-256** as the method.

Restart Postgres for changes to take effect. This can be done either from the Windows Services app or from cmd with Administrator privileges e.g. for Postgresql 15:

```
net stop postgresql-x64-12
net start postgresql-x64-12
```

**WSL Shell Conveniences**

In WSL, add following to your **~/.bashrc** or similar:

```
# Add DNS entry for Windows host
if ! $(cat /etc/hosts | grep -q 'winhost'); then
  echo 'Adding DNS entry for Windows host in /etc/hosts'
  echo '\n# Windows host - added via ~/.bashhrc' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
  echo -e "$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2, "   winhost"}')" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
fi
```

Then reload your .bashrc changes: source ~/.bashrc

I have installed and imported psycopg2 into the code.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

**Error when running the code**
[image]

Thanks
K

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to describe what steps you tried from the answers you linked, and what the results were?

Comment: It has nothing to do with installing `psycopg2-binary`, the port on the WSL virtual machine is not available to you for some reason

Comment: Does WSL still count as "localhost"?

Answer (score 0):

finally able to resolve the issue, i have just replaced the localhost with IP address in pg admin while setting up connection in PG Server

[image]