# Connection refused with postgresql using psycopg2 - connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, fastapi, psycopg2

I am using python fastAPI framework for creating dummy APIs. I have PostgresSQL Server running.

```py
app = FastAPI()

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1", database="fastapi", user="postgres", password="postgres", cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print("Connected to the database")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # If the connection fails, the program will exit
    exit()
```

```
C:\Users\vanshmittal>pg_ctl start -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
waiting for server to start....2024-02-17 12:16:22.273 IST [28300] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2024-02-17 12:16:22.273 IST [28300] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
 done
server started

C:\Users\vanshmittal>netstat -ano | findstr :5432
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       28300
```

When I bring my `uvicorn` webserver up by  `uvicorn app.main:app --reload`, I am getting this

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [7007] using statreload
**connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?**
```

I tried to connect PostgreSQL DB using Tableplus with same credentials as used for psycopg2 and I was able to establish connection.
[image]

`postgresql.conf` file looks like this:-

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

`pg_hba.conf` looks like this:-

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

I am not able to figure out why fastAPI webserver using psycopg2 isn't able to connect the PostgresSql server?

Comment: Just to ask the dumb question first -- you are running uvicorn on the same computer as Postgres?

Comment: I have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on my computer, there I am running uvicorn and Postgres is running on windows. But yeah both on same computer

Comment: But not the same IP address.  If you have WSL2, then it's a VM and it has its own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by Tim, in the comments section. This post helped me in resolving the issue.

[How to connect to windows postgres Database from WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824788/how-to-connect-to-windows-postgres-database-from-wsl)

Instead of using `host="localhost"`, I used the host ip `host="172.25.0.1"`, which I got by running `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'`, I was able to connect to the postgres server from WSL

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [18482] using statreload
**Connected to the database**
INFO:     Started server process [18484]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```